# When I add in content resolver to main activity,my app crashes

Tags: java, android, xml

Below is error log I am getting

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                      Process: com.example.android.apppinventory, PID: 14400
>                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.apppinventory/com.example.android.apppinventory.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; regionStart=1; regionLength=-2
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2581)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
>                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; regionStart=1; regionLength=-2
>                                                                                          at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getFileForUri(FileProvider.java:734)
>                                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.query(FileProvider.java:435)
>                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:1070)
>                                                                                          at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:249)
>                                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:498)
>                                                                                          at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:441)
>                                                                                          at com.example.android.apppinventory.MainActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(MainActivity.java:69)
>                                                                                          at com.example.android.apppinventory.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:45)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1245)
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6286)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2647) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1502) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5763) 
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)

This is an inventory app. Earlier I was interacting with the SQLite database and the app worked well but when I added the concept of content resolver the app crashed.Plz help

```
private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
        //InventoryDbHelper mDbHelper = new InventoryDbHelper(this);
        //SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                InventoryEntry._ID,
                InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME,
                InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
                InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_PRICE,
                InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
                InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_IMAGE
        };
        /**Cursor cursor = db.query(InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null);**/
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
        //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
        TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        try {
            displayView.setText("Number of rows in table are " + cursor.getCount() + "\n\n");
            displayView.append(InventoryEntry._ID + "-" + InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME + "\n");
            int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry._ID);
            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
                String currentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
                displayView.append("\n" + currentID + "-" + currentName);
            }

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: plz format you error trace.

Comment: add MainActivity's displayDatabaseInfo code

Comment: @jackjay how do i do that?

Comment: @PrernaGandhi read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for help.

Comment: @sanjeetkumarSingh I have added the display database info method ...please take a look

Comment: @jackjay Thankyou for the resource ;) Ihave formatted the error and added a new method ..please take a look at it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are appending the strings to a text view which is not valid. Instead use **StringBuilder** for appending strings. Then afterwards set that string to text view. Please refer below code for example.

```
    private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
    //InventoryDbHelper mDbHelper = new InventoryDbHelper(this);
    //SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] projection = {
            InventoryEntry._ID,
            InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME,
            InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION,
            InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_PRICE,
            InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_QUANTITY,
            InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_IMAGE
    };
    /**Cursor cursor = db.query(InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME,projection,null,null,null,null,null);**/
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
    //Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,null);
    TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    try {
        sb.append("Number of rows in table are " + cursor.getCount() + "\n\n");
        sb.append(InventoryEntry._ID + "-" + InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME + "\n");
        int idColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry._ID);
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(InventoryEntry.PRODUCT_NAME);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int currentID = cursor.getInt(idColumnIndex);
            String currentName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            sb.append("\n" + currentID + "-" + currentName);
        }
        displayView.setText(sb.toString());
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But I still am having the same error @sanjeetkumarSingh

Comment: @PrernaGandhi what's InventoryEntry.CONTENT_URI??

Comment: ~public final class InventoryContract {
    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.android.apppinventory";
    public static final String PATH_INVENTORY = "inventory";
    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
    public static final class InventoryEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(BASE_CONTENT_URI, PATH_INVENTORY);
        public final static String TABLE_NAME = "inventory";~